# Javascript or HTML/CSS floating div issue, other issue maybe

Tags: javascript, css, html

*I hate to keep asking questions, but I am just horrible at Javascript although I've gone to several classes. I have a webpage with two divs I want to show ONLY when the viewer clicks a button to do so. Inside the div is a close button.
I dont want to switch to other lightbox stuff or totally change it again. I started is a certain way then had someone kindly change the Javascript to another method so they wouldn't overlap each other.

This is the coding:*

**FIRST DIV + BUTTON**

```
<div id="nodate" style="display:none"><span class="A"> <input type="image" src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/1/6/7/6/16768236/custom_themes/307429121386408805/files/close-icon.png?1384992227202" width="42" onclick="collapse.call(this);" /></span><b>There are no reservations listed under the date you selected. </b>Please select another date or ask for assistance.
<br>
<br>
<image style="border:2px solid #000" src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/1/6/7/6/16768236/custom_themes/307429121386408805/files/shutterstock_9121894.jpg?1385086331177" width="200" />
</div>
<input type="submit" style="background-color: #E0E0E0; padding: 4px; border: solid 2px #000; cursor:pointer; margin: 2px; border-radius: 10px;" value="Friday November 22nd, 2013" onclick="toggle.call(this);"></input>
```

**SECOND DIV + BUTTON (CONTAINS MORE)**

```
<br>
<br>
<div id="nodate2" style="display:none"><span class="A"> <input type="image" src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/1/6/7/6/16768236/custom_themes/307429121386408805/files/close-icon.png?1384992227202" width="42" onclick="collapse.call(this);" /></span><h2>Cool! We’ve got reservations for the date you selected. </h2>

<u>Your name must use a proper format or you will receive a notice that your reservation could not be found.</u>

<ul>
    <li>&bull; Both First &amp; Last</li>
    <li>&bull; First &amp; Last name must have first letter capitalized</li>
    <li>&bull; Single space between first &amp; last name</li>
</ul>Ex: Austin Block
<br><br>
<left>
<b>Input Your Name</b><br>
<form name="login" style="margin: 0px">
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="pass" size="17" onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) event.keyCode=9;" style="width: 152px; margin: 5px;"><br>
<input type="button" value="Click to Continue" style="width : 150px; margin: 3px" onClick="TheLogin(this.form)">
</form><font color="red">(You MUST use the button. Return key will NOT work.)</font>
</center>
<br>
<br>
<image style="border:2px solid #000" src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/1/6/7/6/16768236/custom_themes/307429121386408805/files/reservations2.jpg?1385069953644" width="200" />
</div>

<input type="submit" style="background-color: #E0E0E0; padding: 4px; border: solid 2px #000; cursor:pointer; margin: 2px;  border-radius: 10px;" value="Saturday November 23rd, 2013" onclick="toggle.call(this);"></input>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
var toggle = function () {
var mydiv =this.previousElementSibling;
mydiv.style.display = (mydiv.style.display || 'block') === "block" ? 'none' :'block'
}
var collapse = function(){
this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

*I didnt include the CSS. **What Is Need** is to assign Javascript to specific elements NOT what it is now. I also dont fully understand how its currently working but the way I understand is its just affecting the element/div before the open button. The reason I need to fix this is because when I put it in a table it moves the div (supposed to be positioned absolute) to where the table ends. I dont know why, maybe there is something else causing it but any help is very much appreciated.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script>
        var activeDiv ="";
        var toggle = function () {
            var mydiv = this.previousElementSibling;
            mydiv.style.display = (mydiv.style.display || 'block') === "block" ? 'none' : 'block'
            if( (activeDiv != mydiv.id)&& (activeDiv!=""))
                collapse(activeDiv);
            activeDiv = mydiv.id;
        }
        var collapse = function (id) {
            var activeDiv = document.getElementById(id);
            activeDiv.style.display = 'none';
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am wondering how to specify the div id (do i replace the (id)?). Also, how would I use multiple if I have two of these buttons, toggled divs, on a single page?

Comment: You dont have to replace the id,  The variable activeDiv will always hold the Id of the Div that is visible. it is updated with the latest id in the toggle() method.     activeDiv = mydiv.id;

Comment: You can have multiple divs, your toggle method will handle it - have only one div visible.  But if you want to have more than one div to be visible at the same time ,then you might want to manage the other id too, but in this case it should be good to go.

Comment: They open but the close I have doesnt work.....<input type="image" src="http://www.weebly.com/uploads/1/6/7/6/16768236/custom_themes/307429121386408805/files/close-icon.png?1384992227202" width="42" onclick="collapse.call(this);" />

Comment: I also dont understand how its deciding to open the div I want it to. It is but I'm not specifying it anywhere.

Comment: 1. The Close Problem : The syntax for calling Close(collapse) is the wrong. you need to pass the id of the Div.       onclick="collapse('nodate2')"

Comment: 2. Deciding which div to open : the code         this.previousElementSibling;  gets you the immediately preceding sibling element,without you specifying it, and the toggle method just sets the display property to the current one.  This would work fine for elements in a sequence, But if you are planning to use multiple divs in any order I suggest you pass the div id to toggle method, and set the display property of it directly.